# Concatenated two dataframes but remove duplicates that were originally only in the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to do a simple concatenate of two dataframes but I want to remove duplicates. The tricky thing here is I only want to remove the duplicates that were orignally in my first dataframe but keep the other. In addition my unique "key" consists of two columns.

Eg. :

*source* =

```
key_part1      key_part2     number
   1              A            10
   2              A            20
```

*addition* =

```
key_part1      key_part2     number
   1              A            30
   2              B            50
   2              B            60
```

So after the join I want my result to look like this:

```
key_part1      key_part2     number
   1              A            10
   2              A            20
   2              B            50
   2              B            60
```

I could solve it by removing all elements from the *addition* frame that has a key that is also present in *source* and concatenating afterwards but this feels like a work around. And it feels like there is a more elegant solution, however I am not able to figure this out. Anybody any idea?

Comment: have your tried drop duplicates on the first and second data frame then merge left

Comment: I cannot think of a better approach than the one mentioned in your question.

Comment: if you want a less elegant solution, let me know. as for more elegant, im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

With the following dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame(
    {"key_part1": {0: 1, 1: 2}, "key_part2": {0: "A", 1: "A"}, "number": {0: 10, 1: 20}}
)

addition = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "key_part1": {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2},
        "key_part2": {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "B"},
        "number": {0: 30, 1: 50, 2: 60},
    }
)
```

You could try this:

```py
df = source.append(
    addition[
        ~(addition["key_part1"].astype(str) + addition["key_part2"]).isin(
            (source["key_part1"].astype(str) + source["key_part2"]).to_list()
        )
    ],
    ignore_index=True,
)

print(df)
# Output
   key_part1 key_part2  number
0          1         A      10
1          2         A      20
2          2         B      50
3          2         B      60
```